# Can't import script in Neo4j

Tags: import, neo4j

I'm trying to import a script to Neo4j by drag-and-drop but when I drag the file over the Import area in Neo4j Browser, the cursor keeps the blocking symbol, like if I cannot drop the file over there.

I've already tried with `.txt`, `.cyp`, `.cypher`, `.cql`. Does anyone have an idea of what I could be doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't sound like you're doing anything incorrectly. Though I have, in the past, experienced this problem (when dragging a file over to the import box, the cursor just maintains that red 'no' symbol for extended periods of time) when the Neo4j browser instance is running slowly - if, for example, you have multiple large graph-rendered result sets in your results pane, this can slow things down dramatically.

In these cases, I've simply restarted my browser (or sometimes even my computer) and everything seems to run better. If this fails, I'd ensure your browser is up to date or perhaps even try a different browser.